# Type to access e.target.value with useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Consider simply a toggle component which can be considered as a checkbox, and a form component that handles the toggle.

```
export const ToggleSwitch2 = ({ id, checked, onChange }:
  { id:string, checked:boolean, onChange: any }) => { //any type here

  return(
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        className="toggle-switch-checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.checked)} //Problem here
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export const Form2 = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  return(
    <ToggleSwitch2 id="toggleSwitch" checked={checked} onChange={setChecked} />
  );
};
```

Types I tried for my onChage function:

1.- `onChange: (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>void`

2.- `onChange: (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>void`

3.- `onChange: (e:BaseSyntheticEvent)=>void`

4.- `onChange: (e:SyntheticEvent)=>void`

I cannot find the fit, because the hook returns a `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>` type, and the input `onChange` type in the toggle is `React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>.onChange?: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined`.

What is the type of the `onChange` argument function in the `ToggleSwitch2` component?

Comment: please change it: className="toggle-switch-checkbox"

Comment: thanks for spotting that out

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. what you are passing down as a prop is just the setChecked hook function, it knows nothing of the events

Comment: will you share more of the code please?

Comment: rest of the code is not very meaningfull. Just the react `function App() {}` function with the `<Form2>` component and the respective `import`s

Comment: What error are you getting? This is compiling without problem for me...

Comment: yes, because the type is `any`. The question is what is the type that fits there instead of `any` :)

Comment: simply (checked: boolean)=> void should work. you are trying to figure out the signature of the onchange function of your input element, but what you are passing down as a prop is simply the hook function

Comment: thanks for your comment. I need the `id` and the `onChange` defined, so that I can then set the passed in arguments in the component. I dont unsderstand your proposal

Comment: I'm just trying to follow react advice of using [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) but from a functional component with a hook instead of a class component. Hope that makes sense

Comment: now I see you point @Syder. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are trying  to type your `onChange` property as it is an event handler for checkbox, but it is not. You are passing `(checked: boolean) => void`, and call it inside actual event handler. If you want to pass actual event handler,  function should look like this: `(event) => setChecked(event.target.checked)` and whole code would be like this:

```js
import { ChangeEventHandler, useState } from "react";
interface ToggleSwitchProps {
  id: string;
  checked: boolean;
  onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
}
export const ToggleSwitch2 = ({ id, checked, onChange }: ToggleSwitchProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        className="toggle-switch-checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ToggleSwitch2
      id="toggleSwitch"
      checked={checked}
      onChange={(event) => setChecked(event.target.checked)}
    />
  );
};
```